# Wordpress спарсить json и впихнуть его в шаблонную страницу elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, json, wordpress-плагины

Возможно ли написание плагина для WP или приложения, чтобы парсить загружаемые данные формата json на шаблон Elementor и создания на самом сайте ссылки на запись.

Comment: Почему нет - все возможно

Comment: @KAGGDesign и как это можно реализовать? может статьи какие есть?

Comment: не знаю, не видел

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php